# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' in Networkx random walk code that was previously working

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, networkx

I had what I thought was a working random walk over a networkx node/edge graph.
I recently decided to update Anaconda using the navigator and then I came back to run my program again and all of a sudden it has stopped working.  Instead, I now get the error code:

```
runfile('C:/Users/e17/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/e17/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-64-51811f4d02fc>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/e17/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/e17/.spyder-py3')

File "C:\Users\e17\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 688, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\e17\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/e17/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 19, in <module>
if rc in NodesVisited:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I had been using a while loop to fill a dictionary using the nodes that were visited during the random walk.  This was really nice in that the dictionary lent itself to a lot of downstream analysis.  I am now completely lost in how to fix this.  I gather that I need to provide a key for the dictionary, but I'm not quite sure how to populate the dictionary after providing the keys.  Anyway, here is the code:

```
import networkx as nx
import random


G_fb = nx.karate_club_graph()
counter = 0
loops = 1


mylist = [];
#run while loop for multiple attempts at random walker
while loops <= 1000:

    rc = random.choice(G_fb.nodes())
    NodesVisited = {}

    #Execute random walk
    while counter <= 11:
        if rc in NodesVisited:
                NodesVisited[rc] += 1
        else:
                NodesVisited[rc] = 1

        Neighbors = G_fb.neighbors(rc)
        rc = random.choice(Neighbors)
        counter += 1

    #Organize the node list in most visited with decreasing order
    MostVisited = sorted(NodesVisited, key = NodesVisited.get,reverse = True)

    #Separate the top 10 most visited vertex
    top_top = MostVisited[:10]

    #create a list of most visited sites for plotting for each iteration  
    mylist.append(top_top)


    loops = loops + 1
    counter = 0
print ('all done!')
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is `rc` after `rc = random.choice(G_fb.nodes())` and after `rc = random.choice(Neighbors)`? You need to print these values and inspect them. Presumably the API changed in an updated version of the library that came with the Anaconda upgrade

Comment: Yup. rc is meant to pick a random neighbor to hop to for the next step of the walk.  Sorry, my commenting sucks.

Comment: That wasn't what I said. I said you need to _print_ these values and inspect them. One (or both) of them is a dictionary.

Comment: Ah, yes you are correct.  I didn't understand before.  Thank you.  That seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In networkx 1.11, `G.nodes()` is a `list`.  In newer versions it is a `NodeView` object.  This change is the cause of your problems.  A random choice from it turns out to be returning some random node's data, which is a dict.

So

```
if rc in NodesVisited
```

checks whether `rc` is a key of `NodesVisited`.  To do this, it needs to hash `rc`, but it's no longer a node, it's a dict, so it can't.

To fix this, change

```
rc = random.choice(G_fb.nodes())
```

to

```
rc = random.choice(list(G_fb.nodes()))
```

You'll similarly have to change

```
Neighbors = G_fb.neighbors(rc)
```

to

```
Neighbors = list(G_fb.neighbors(rc))
```

Comment: You are a genius.  Thank you, this worked perfectly.  i was starting to think I was losing it.